# ESXI merge two server to share their resources?

Tags: esxi

Is there any way to combine two ESXI host with each other so that they can share their resource with each an other? Or is there an way to run VM on two ESXI so that it will use both ESXI resources or distribute resources among them is this possible on ESXI hypervisor or is there any hypervisor available to run VM on multiple node? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to combine two ESXI host with each other so that they can share their resource with each an other?

you can merge datastores by vSan Technology

> is there an way to run VM on two ESXI so that it will use both ESXI
>   resources or distribute resources among them is this possible on ESXI
>   hypervisor

no for now

> is there any hypervisor available to run VM on multiple node

nope :(

> Is there any solution?

you can ask for specify what you need and you will find alot of answers that may help you